# Join query SQL problem duplicate rows primary keys?

Tags: sql

[image: duplicate rows]

I have an issue with duplicate rows in the join. No matter which join,  i will have duplicate rows at ticket_id or itemsId

do you know any reason why it duplicates ??

Comment: The first column is different.  Those don't look like duplicates to me.  That said, the images are really hard to read and that is one reason why you should put the data in questions as *text tables* and not images.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your screenshot and the arrangement of rows, it would appear that the reason for the primary keys being duplicated is because you are doing the join the wrong way round. The left table has many different things which align with the primary key of the right table.

Comment: I have change but still the result gives again duplicates

Comment: Dirty data then